# java HttpClient 403 forbidden problem?

Tags: java, httpclient

I using HttpClient api to authenticate to a web site:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, 443),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(args[0], args[1]));

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://..........");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        System.out.println("Response content length: "
                + entity.getContentLength());
    }
```

I have this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Response content length: -1
```

But with a browser i have access to this page with the same login and password !!!!

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: is that a type-o, or are you connecting to that url via http and not https?

Answer (score 2):

You construct the AuthScope object with the port parameter set to 443 (default port for HTTPS). However, you create the HttpGet object with the URL pointing to HTTP (with default port 80).

Either try to construct the AuthScope using:

```
new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT)
```

or make sure that ports will match.

Comment: I change ,but the same response !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look carefully at how the browser is actually authenticating.

What you are trying to do is (I think) send the credentials using HTTP Basic Authentication.  If the site is set up to only allow form-based authentication and a session cookie, then it will ignore the header containing the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Version of the `HttpClient` you are using is whats causing the `403`.

Try

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();
```